# Windows 8 Mail on secondary monitor

Tags: windows-8, email, multiple-monitors, windows-live-mail

How can i set the Windows 8 Mail application to start up on my secondary screen? I've installed 'Actual Monitors' for this purpose, but because i can't find an actual path to the application, 'Actual Moniters' can't handle to open the Mail app on the second monitor.

Does anyone know to get an actual path to the Windows 8 Mail application, or even better a way without a third part application to launch the mail on the secondary monitor?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Windows 8, or 8.1?  By "Windows Mail Application" are you referring to the Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI Mail app?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro. Yes By "Windows 8 Mail Application" I'm refering to the Metro/Modern UI Mail app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that fits me. Instead of actual monitors I'm using ModernMix from Stardock. It works perfectly.

http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/index.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the metro apps to run from command line or similar, because they run in an app container without accessing the `IApplicationActivationManager` interface. If 'Actual Moniters' isn't making a call to the `IApplicationActivationManager` interface, it cannot run metro apps.

Comment: Ah yea, that makes sense, thanks.
Is there any way do it with without 'Actual monitors'?

Comment: @user1868569 you can look for an program that uses the IApplicationActivationManager interface, unforunately I don't know of any. Or you can create your own if you're into that. Another option would be to use 'Actual Monitors' with something like mozilla thunderbird